# Attachment size limit to export data?

Tags: netsuite

I'd like to export my data via email everyday from a safesearch, problem is the (I think) limit of 5mb. There's a way to overcome it? Like for example send multiple files.

Thanks

Comment: Are you working with Suitscript?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of emailing file, maybe email a link to the file in NS?  Or, use scripting to write the file to a third party system (SFTP?)?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to email a link accessable from the outside? I've Search info about it but got nothing... could you address me? Thanks